# Could not upload files error in GitFTP

Tags: git-ftp

I'm following tutorial on http://anantgarg.com/2013/09/25/git-ftp-for-windows/ and get error:

```
$ git ftp init
There are 720 files to sync:
[1 of 720] Buffered for upload '.gitignore'.
[2 of 720] Buffered for upload 'wp-config-sample.php'.
....
[24 of 720] Buffered for upload 'wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/admin/post-types/writepanels/order-item-html.php'.
Uploading ...
fatal: Could not upload files., exiting...
```

what could be the problem? I've set the password using quotes ( 'mypassword' ) but same error still occur

Answer (score 13):

You can see output of the exact error by using the '-v' flag for super-verbose output.

The problem could be one of the following

1. Incorrect FTP credentials - check that the server, username, and password are all correct.

   - **URL/server**: make sure to include the protocol with the URL if not standard FTP
     (`sftp://ftp.domain.com:22`).
   - **Password**: Try also removing the quotes around the password
2. The server path is not set or incorrect. Often, an FTP login takes you to the server root. You may not have write-privileges there. You'll need to set the site root path.

   - try setting path with in the URL argument `ftp://ftp.domain.com/public_html`

Try doing an 'init' via command-line arguments instead (NOT via Git config settings) and set verbose output using '-v':

```
git ftp init -u username -p 'password' -v ftpserverurl.com
```

Comment: setting verbose requires a single dash, not a double dash (unless you're using `--verbose`)

Comment: @Tim yes, you are correct, thank you. You can alternately set -vv for "very verbose" to get even more details.

Comment: Hii Luke and dpidan, I am getting below error in bitbucket when i push from code from licalhost to bitbucket: "fatal: Could not upload files., exiting..."
can you please give me solution for this error
thanks in advance

Answer (score -5):

I think you should use [ftp-git](http://redino.net/ftp-git), it's a GUI tool to push changed files in git repository to ftp server. And it's more error-friendly.

You can check the changed files in GUI way, and it can save your ftp connection details for future use.

Comment: How is this even relevant?