# bitbucket pipeline deploy ftp

Tags: git, ftp, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm fairly new to deployment and pipelines, however today I managed to have them working on a simple test site.
I'm now trying to replicate the same on a proper website but it fails during the init. I have many files to upload (~3000) as it's the first upload and I'm not sure if it's failing because of this or for some other reasons (the log doesn't say anything specific). Is there any more detailed log that gives more information about what's going on?

Thank you

here's my yml

image: samueldebruyn/debian-git

```
pipelines:
    branches:
      master:
       - step:
          script:
            - apt-get update
            - apt-get -qq install git-ftp
            - git ftp init --user $FTPU --passwd $FTPP ftp_url
```

and this is the log. if always fail at the 43rd file

```
git ftp init --user $FTPU --passwd $FTPP ftp_url
+ git ftp init --user $FTPU --passwd $FTPP ftp_url
There are 2914 files to sync:
[1 of 2914] Buffered for upload URL
[2 of 2914] ...

....
[43 of 2914] Buffered for upload URL
Uploading ...
fatal: Could not upload files., exiting...
```

the log with -v

```
Thu May 18 13:24:27 UTC 2017: [43 of 2914] Buffered for upload url.
Thu May 18 13:24:27 UTC 2017: Uploading ...
curl: (25) Failed FTP upload: 553
curl: (25) Failed FTP upload: 553
curl: (25) Failed FTP upload: 553
curl: (25) Failed FTP upload: 553
curl: (25) Failed FTP upload: 553
curl: (25) Failed FTP upload: 553
curl: (25) Failed FTP upload: 553
curl: (25) Failed FTP upload: 553
curl: (9) Failed to MKD dir: 550
curl: (25) Failed FTP upload: 553
curl: (25) Failed FTP upload: 553
curl: (25) Failed FTP upload: 553
curl: (25) Failed FTP upload: 553
curl: (25) Failed FTP upload: 553
curl: (25) Failed FTP upload: 553
curl: (25) Failed FTP upload: 553
curl: (25) Failed FTP upload: 553
curl: (25) Failed FTP upload: 553
curl: (25) Failed FTP upload: 553
curl: (25) Failed FTP upload: 553
curl: (25) Failed FTP upload: 553
curl: (25) Failed FTP upload: 553
curl: (25) Failed FTP upload: 553
curl: (25) Failed FTP upload: 553
curl: (9) Failed to MKD dir: 550
curl: (25) Failed FTP upload: 553
curl: (9) Failed to MKD dir: 550
curl: (25) Failed FTP upload: 553
curl: (9) Failed to MKD dir: 550
curl: (25) Failed FTP upload: 553
curl: (25) Failed FTP upload: 553
curl: (25) Failed FTP upload: 553
curl: (25) Failed FTP upload: 553
curl: (25) Failed FTP upload: 553
curl: (25) Failed FTP upload: 553
Thu May 18 13:24:41 UTC 2017: fatal: Could not upload files., exiting...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try at least, as [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21442656/6309), to add a -v to your `git ftp init` command. That will give you a better idea.

Also, of course, try that same command with just a few files to upload, in order to determine if the number of files is the issue: [it was the case in 2014](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23051944/6309) ([issue 88](https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp/issues/88), in theory fixed by [PR 104](https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp/pull/104))

Comment: ok thanks, I updated the post with the -v log which for my basic knowledge is still not helpful..

Comment: @SkaFrenz Did you test with just a few files?

Comment: @SkaFrenz Is is a right issue? (https://serverfault.com/questions/841158/curl-25-failed-ftp-upload-553-to-vsftpd-docker, https://github.com/panubo/docker-vsftpd/issues/1)

Comment: tested with just few files and still not working..I now contacted my host provider to see if there's something wrong..

Answer (score 0):

It seems the FTP account you are using does not have enough permission to create the directories needed. This causes the script to retry continuously until it timed out.

```
curl: (9) Failed to MKD dir: 550
```

Try testing the account using an FTP application first like FileZilla then replicate the creation of directory to see if it will allow you to do so.